# element is running again and again

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to execute `onchange` function with  GreaseMonkey script, I'm using this code :

```
var element = document.getElementById("country");

if ('fireEvent' in element)
    element.fireEvent("onchange");
else {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

document.getElementById("country").value = "3";
```

but its executing/reloading again and again, so how can I execute it once only?
I'm trying to execute script on this html code :

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="form.submit()" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="1">US</option>

                  <option value="2">UK</option>

                  <option value="3">FR</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: thanks loxxy, can you please change this code for me, I'm very newbie in coding, thanks again...

Comment: Why does it reload? On what page do you execute this? Is this the whole script?

Comment: yes it is the whole script, and I'm trying to run this script on this html code :   <select name="country" id="country" onchange="form.submit()" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
                                         <option value="1" selected="">US</option>
      
                                         <option value="2">UK</option>
      
                                         <option value="3">FR</option></select>

Comment: experts please help??????

Answer (score 0):

Onchange is firing every time an update is done to the select.  An update is done to the select element as soon as it is loaded, to set the first element to selected.  This fires the form submit automatically.  If you don't have an action attribute on the form it is submitted to the same exact page, or if the action is to the same page.  And the whole cycle start again.

Comment: thanks, can you give me the solution code, that works only once on page load?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think anyone will just give you the code here.  We all had to pay our dues and learn it.

Answer (score 0):

1. So you load the HTML
2. Trigger the event `onchange`
3. Which triggers `form.submit()`
4. Which takes you to step 1?

Have a feeling `onchange="form.submit()"` is the culprit. But you would need to share more.

Comment: yes, you are correct, its starting again from step1, and again and again. this code is working,its triggering onchange correctly,  but problem is it should execute only once.